# cordova Zbar plugin cant be used in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

I'm new in ionic 2 and I use Typescript. I need use this pugin https://github.com/tjwoon/csZBar. When I follow steps in ionic2(https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/zbar/),

```js
import { ZBar } from 'ionic-native';
```

,but the Zbar is not found in ionic-native;
I have try many methods to use the plugin in ionic2 of typescript.just like:

1. ```js
   declare var navigator : any;
   @Component({
       templateUrl: 'build/pages/special/main/more/more.html',
       providers: [Router, UserService,Navbar]
   })
   export class MorePage {

       constructor(private nav: NavController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private router: Router) {
       }

       scanZBar() {
           navigator.zBar.scan({camera: "back", drawSight: true}, data=> {
               this.showAlert("warning", data);
           }, data=> {
               this.showAlert("warning", data);
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. `scanZBar(){
       (<any>window).plugins.zBar.scan({camera: "back", drawSight: true}, data=>{
           this.showAlert("warning",data);
       }, data=>{
           this.showAlert("warning",data);
       });
   }`

they all not worked.
Can somebody help me？I have made lots of search.